# Calculate cumulative product / multiple

Tags: r, multiplication

Suppose I have a vector `x` as:

```
x <- c(X1, X2, X3, ..., Xn)
```

I want to write a function that automatically get the result series like this:

```
y <- c(X1, X1*X2, X1*X2*X3, ..., X1*X2*X3*...*Xn)
```

Can someone tell me how to do this in R?

Answer (score 9):

Have a look at `?cumprod`:

```
 cumprod(1:10)
 # [1]       1       2       6      24     120     720    5040   40320  362880 3628800
```